# Map a clickable area

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does someone know how to click just in the triangle area without affecting the other areas?

I tried to create a triangle div `clip-path`. But it not supported by Internet Explorer.

I investigated a lot but I didn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Post your HTML, CSS and Javascript code, What you have tried to get this done?

Comment: Hi ,Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code, can you please put your code

Comment: Hi guys, the code it's very extensive and the question is simple that's why I don't share any code. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by using CSS3 transform

```css
html,
body {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  width: 26em;
  height: 26em;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -13em;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(17deg) scale(1);
          transform: rotate(17deg) scale(1);
}
.nav-wrapper li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 1px solid white;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
          transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -5em;
  transition: border 0.3s ease;
}
.nav-wrapper li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(17deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg) skew(17deg);
}
.nav-wrapper li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg) skew(17deg);
          transform: rotate(72deg) skew(17deg);
}
.nav-wrapper li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg) skew(17deg);
          transform: rotate(144deg) skew(17deg);
}
.nav-wrapper li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg) skew(17deg);
          transform: rotate(216deg) skew(17deg);
}
.nav-wrapper li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(288deg) skew(17deg);
          transform: rotate(288deg) skew(17deg);
}
.nav-wrapper li a {
  display: block;
  height: 14.5em;
  width: 14.5em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7.25em;
  right: -7.25em;
  background-color: #81d8d0;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-46deg);
          transform: skew(-46deg);
  transition: opacity 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}
.nav-wrapper li a:hover {
  background-color: #a8e4df;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is I need. But this has support for IE ?

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? CSS3 2D transform is only supported since IE9.

Comment: I'm using mac hahaha but I need do that for IE9 and next. But I checked out and works perfectly. Thank you so much dude :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` tag along with `areas` . A lot of online tools help you to generate the areas . One of them is : https://www.image-map.net/

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj8iT.png" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Google" title="Google" href="http://www.google.com" coords="181,24,47,129,186,179" shape="poly">
    <area target="" alt="" title="" href="" coords="" shape="0">
</map>
```

Comment: Yes, this working perfect with images. But how Can I map every div, because each triangle was created with CSS.

Comment: I don't think you could achieve that using `CSS` , However you still has a chance to try dealing with `SVG` tag which give you a more flexible capabilities . Check the following article https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/